# ADB to Launch android browser with given url

Tags: android, shell, adb, monkey

I am trying to send a commend via ADB to launch different browsers with a given URL.
I only know the package names of the browsers so I used:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.android.chrome -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

This way I could open the app with only the package name, but I couldn't pass any URL to it.

I could pass a URL to chrome using:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://www.bbc.com/
```

but this requires more then just package name.

Trying to combine these two didn't work:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.android.chrome -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1 -d https://www.yahoo.com
```

What is the correct way to pass a URL to a browser using only the package name with monkey?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.facebook.com

Comment: This does not answer the question I asked, and as you can see it's the same line I used in my  second example. Thank you for the try.